# How to make setInterval start again after clearInterval is called

Tags: jquery, setinterval

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Hello, I'm trying to make a basic slider, the slider should automatically slide every 10 seconds, however when a user clicks the next slide button(.next) I want it to slide to the next slide and reset the setInterval timer to start from 10 seconds from the click

**What it's currently doing**

At the moment it's automatically sliding, however once the next button is clicked it stops the setInterval alltogether instead of resetting the setInterval timer

```
var slideTimer;
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);


$(".next").click(function(){
    nextSlide();
});

function nextSlide() {
    $(".sliders img:first").appendTo(".sliders"); 
    $(".next").click(function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    });
};
```

Comment: Just set the setInterval again when you clean it.

Comment: 10 seconds or 3 seconds or 3 seconds with 10 seconds pause on click?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pause for 10 seconds, then you can try this:

```js
// var slideTimer; // don't need this as you declare it below
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000); // start slide show


$(".next").click(function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);  // clear the interval
    nextSlide();                // show the next slide
    setTimeout(function() {
      slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000); 
    },7000); // start the interval in 7 seconds which will show in 10 seconds (3000+7000)
});

function nextSlide() {
    $(".sliders img:first").appendTo(".sliders"); // only need to append in this - don't need to rebind
};
```

If you just want the interval to resume in 10 seconds and the interval to BE 10 seconds then this is enough:

```js
// var slideTimer; // don't need this as you declare it below
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 10000); // start slide show 10 secs


$(".next").click(function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);  // clear the interval
    slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 10000);  // restart
});

function nextSlide() {
    $(".sliders img:first").appendTo(".sliders"); // only need to append in this - don't need to rebind
};
```

Comment: ah i missed the 10 second pause requirement!

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to do something like this:

```js
// var slideTimer; // don't need this as you declare it below
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000); // start slide show


$(".next").click(function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);  // clear the interval
    nextSlide();                // show the next slide
    slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000); // start the interval again so next will show in 3 seconds - if this needs to start after 10 seconds, put it in a timeout of 7 seconds
});

function nextSlide() {
    $(".sliders img:first").appendTo(".sliders"); // only need to append in this - don't need to rebind
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var slideTimer;
var slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);


$(".next").click(function(){
    nextSlide();
});

function nextSlide() {
    $(".sliders img:first").appendTo(".sliders"); 
    $(".next").click(function(){
      clearInterval(slideTimer);
      slideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);//add this to your code
    });
};
```